# Pb to insert a new value in a dropdown

Tags: php

I whish to insert a new static  value in a dropdown

With this code I have in my dropdown

- Customer
- my dynamic information php

.

```
$values_customers_group_id[0] = array ('id' =>'0', 'text' => 'customer');

for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($customers_group); $i<$n; $i++) {
  $values_customers_group_id[$i+1] = array ('id' =>$customers_group[$i]['id'], 'text' =>$customers_group[$i]['text']);
}
```

Now I try to have :

- All customers
- Customer
- my dynamic information php

How to add All customers (with another value like 'id'=>'-1', 'text'=>'All customers' or  'id'=>'99', 'text'=>'All customers' for ewample) in dropdown in more  ?

Tk

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your old $customer_group is:

```
$customers_group[] = array('id'=>0, 'text'=>'Clients Normaux');
$customers_group[] = array('id'=>1, 'text'=>'Revendeurs Canada');
```

Looks like all you need is to push the "static" entries into it

```
$customers_group[] = array('id'=>99, 'text'=>'normal customers group');
```

$customers_group will then return

```
    Array
(
[0] = Array
    (
        [id] = 0
        [text] = Clients Normaux
    )

[1] = Array
    (
        [id] = 1
        [text] = Revendeurs Canada
    )

[2] = Array
    (
        [id] = 99
        [text] = normal customers group
    )

)
```

You will not need $values_customers_group_id and the for loop

just make your html select with $customers_group

```
<?php
  echo "<select name="customers_group_id">\n";
  foreach ($customers_group as $customer)
  {
    echo "  <option value='".$customer['id']'."'>".$customer['text']."</option>\n";
  }
  echo "</select>\n";
?>
```

this should return

```
<select name="customers_group_id">
  <option value="0">Clients Normaux</option>
  <option value="1">Revendeurs Canada</option>
  <option value="99">normal customers group</option>
</select>
```